# Find the most common occurrence of a series of numbers in a N x 4 array

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I have an array of 1M rows and 4 columns. I want to find the most common occurrence of a series of numbers in all the columns. i.e., if  8.1, -3.2, 3.4, 5.1 occurs the maximum number of times, I would like to get that and if possible, the indices of the rows.

I am trying to use Python's collections/counter, but can't seem to get what I need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) per columns with select first values to `Series`:

```
s = df.apply(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
```

And then for indices compare values by `Series` in [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and create dictionary:

```
ind = {k: v.index[v].tolist() for k, v in df.eq(s).items()}
```